# Constant in an inequality

Tags: calculus

There exists a unique positive constant $a$ so that
$$a^x≥\frac{x}{2}+1$$
for all real numbers $x$. Find $⌊100a⌋$. Since it is given all real numbers, i took really big numbers and found that $a$ was tending to $1$. But then the answer should have been 100 which is incorrect. Why?

Comment: You should look at the series expansion of $a^x = e^{\ln(a)x}$

Comment: Are you looking for the smallest such value of $a$? Because there are infinitely many values for which the above holds.

Comment: I think yes. But it's not mentioned in the question.

Comment: No, its unique. Note that the inequality is required to hold for all reals, in particular for $x \to 0$ (that is the critical value to investigate!), which implies $a = \sqrt{e}$.

Answer (score 3):

We have $a^x-\frac{x}{2}-1 = (\ln(a)-\frac{1}{2})x+\mathcal O(x^2)$.

For $|x|$ small, this can only be non-negative, when the coefficient of the linear term vanishes. So $a = \sqrt{e}$ is necessary for the inequality to hold. For sufficiency look at the derivative of $f(x) := (\sqrt{e})^x-\frac{x}{2}-1$ and thus conclude a global minimum at $x=0$ with $f(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $a = \sqrt{e}$. Can you take it from here?